# can SSH into EC2 ubuntu server as a root not as a ubuntu user

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, amazon-ec2, ssh, ssh-keys

Hi i have 3 ubuntu EC2 instance from server A,B i need to ssh into server C. i have done the following steps in server A,B.

```
1) Created a ssh key for the username - jenkins
```

copied the public key from the server A than server B and added into server c's

```
2) vi ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

than changed the folder access of ~/.ssh and authorized_key file as follows

```
3) chmod 600 ~/.ssh/
   chmod 700 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

now from the server A running ssh command as following it loged in into server C as ubuntu user.

```
4) ssh -i privatekey ubuntu@12.12.12.12
```

When i am doing same thing from server B i am getting the following error

```
5) ssh -i privatekey ubuntu@12.12.12.12
```

error

```
 Warning: Identity file -i not accessible: No such file or directory.
 ssh: Could not resolve hostname /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/mykey: Name or service not known
 jenkins@ip-11-11-11-99:/home/ubuntu# ssh -v -i /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/mykey ubuntu@12.12.12.12
 OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
 debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
 debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
 debug1: Connecting to 12.12.12.12 [12.12.12.12] port 22.
 debug1: Connection established.
 debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
 debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/mykey type 1
 debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
 debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/mykey-cert type -1
 debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
 debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
 debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
 debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
 debug1: Authenticating to 12.12.12.12:22 as 'ubuntu'
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
 debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
 debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
 debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
 debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
 debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:28Mc4WE3B22oZ2ClomLspX5gQtwmzdNg82XEHgpI+vE
 debug1: Host '12.12.12.12' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
 debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:3
 debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
 debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
 debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
 debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
 debug1: Offering RSA public key: /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/mykey
 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
 debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
 Permission denied (publickey).
```

But when i am running SSH from server B to login as a root it logged in as a root

```
6) ssh -i privatekey root@12.12.12.12
```

i am confused on what i missed in server B. why it's ignoring to login as a Ubuntu but root it's working. if access right issue means then how it's working for server A.

Someone please help thanks in advance.

Comment: my guess is you copied the wrong public key(root not ubuntu) into authorized_keys ... you can confirm it by comparing the keys

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi i suspect that in Server C. when u added the server B's public key u might have been added in only root user's authorized_keys file. To confirm. ssh into server C and login as a Ubuntu user and run check the authorized_keys file using following command.

```
 vi ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

i am sure that you did not added the server B's public key in this file.you added it in root user's authorized_keys. if it's blank or only default key is present add server b public key and try again. and let us know it worked or not.

Comment: some tutorials create an user as soon as they ssh to the server, but they are somehow connected as root. in ec2 is kinda different since it connects as ubuntu user, this is kind of confusing, should i create a new user (which they recommend for when connecting through root) and grant sudo group priviledges? or would this be overkill?

Comment: someone answered in fb: ubuntuu should be fine. I don't usually deploy to AWS, so I'm used to coming in as root, making a new user and doing my own server hardening.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting the question.

**Problem:** you might have generated keys with different user:

Just follow below steps and you will be good to go:

**0) Delete ~/.ssh**
Delete previous settings. Don't worry, we will start fresh

**1) Copy Public key from A & B to server C**
Login to server A as ubuntu user
$ ssh-keygen
Accept the default file locations
This will generate keys
$ ssh-copy-id ubuntu@
Type the password

**2) Follow same steps on Server B**
**3) Yay!!! you are good to go**

Now test your login. You don't need to change permisssi

Try adding below lines in the ~/.ssh/config

Permissions: -rw-r--r--

HOST  C

IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

User your_user_name

Hostname C

Comment: {noformat}
HOST  C
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
User <your username>
Hostname <C>
{noformat}